# Extracting Count of distinct values from PHP Multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've multidimential PHP Array array

```
 $_SESSION['alldata'][0]["thisisval1"] = 1
 $_SESSION['alldata'][0]["markedval1"] = 1
 $_SESSION['alldata'][0]["herechcked"] = 1

 $_SESSION['alldata'][1]["thisisval1"] = 2
 $_SESSION['alldata'][1]["markedval1"] = 1
 $_SESSION['alldata'][1]["herechcked"] = 10

 $_SESSION['alldata'][2]["thisisval1"] = 1
 $_SESSION['alldata'][2]["markedval1"] = 0
 $_SESSION['alldata'][2]["herechcked"] = 1

 $_SESSION['alldata'][3]["thisisval1"] = 3
 $_SESSION['alldata'][3]["markedval1"] = 0
 $_SESSION['alldata'][3]["herechcked"] = 1

 $_SESSION['alldata'][4]["thisisval1"] = 2
 $_SESSION['alldata'][4]["markedval1"] = 1
 $_SESSION['alldata'][4]["herechcked"] = 7
```

**What is required is :**

1. Get list of distinct values of "thisisval1" in the array
2. Get Count of array elements with "markedval1" = 1 with "thisisval1" = 1

Currently I'm thinking of running loop on $_SESSION['alldata'] and get values required above; 
Is there any SMART way to do same?

Comment: If these values are retrieved from a database, depending on the length of the array, it's better for you to go for a query, instead of the loop. If not, I think there isn't a smart way.

Comment: Even if you could hack something together in `array_map()` or whatever, you'd STILL be running at loop at some point, whether yourself explicity, or implicitly within whatever array function(s) you end up using.

Comment: Is there any way to use array_unique and array_count_values on multidimensional array?

Answer (score 1):

```
 echo '<pre>';
 $newarray = array_values($arr);
 $i=0;
 $j=0;//thisisval1
 $distinctarray = array();
 foreach($newarray[0] as $k=>$v){

 if($v['thisisval1']){
    if(!in_array($v['thisisval1'],$distinctarray)){
    $distinctarray[] = $v['thisisval1'];
 }
 }

 if($v['thisisval1'] ==1){

 $i+=1;
 }elseif($v['markedval1'] ==1){
 $j+=1;
 }
 }
 echo 'count for thisisval1='.$i;
  echo 'count for markedval1='.$j;
 print_r($distinctarray);
```

output

```
count for thisisval1=2
count for markedval1=2
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
)
```

Comment: Thanks Amarjit, I was trying few options using : array_unique and array_count_values